# What recording cable is suitable for F999R?

Tags: sound

F999R is a needle microphone device, with following outputs:

- outputs for headphones, what are included
- some kind of "recording" output.

Hearing through the headphones provided is fine, however if you use standard small audio cable instead, or if you try to use this cable for "recording" output, to make a record, this does not work. It seems that the standard small audio output, what you would normally use for recording, is wrong, and i have no idea what i should use instead. In Internet there is no additional info provided. Maybe someone have used it and knows the answer?
Thanks for help.

Comment: Assuming an analog signal is provided, there are a very limited number of wiring possibilities. Start by assuming the connections are similar to the headphones provided and purchase some appropriate connectors (you can google via images these days).  Use a multimeter in AC mode with the connectors to determine where signal exists.

Comment: yes it is the connection what is  like similar to regular headphones, however there is some kind of difference, because as said, only headphones provided are working, and recording not - both in headphones and recording output,  i get just "buzzing" from it

Comment: Probably just pinned differently. Use a meter on the connection where the headphones work to find where the correct AC signal is at. You may have to cut up an audio cable to get signals to the meter.